# AODE Machine Learning in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability

I wanted to know if really AODE may be better than Naive Bayes in its way, as the description says:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AnDE/AnDE.pdf

--> "AODE achieves highly accurate classification by averaging over all of a small space."

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-Naive-Bayes-classifier-and-AODE

--> "AODE is a weird way of relaxing naive bayes' independence assumptions. It is no longer a generative model, but it relaxes the independence assumptions in a slightly different (and less principled) way than logistic regression does. It replaces the convex optimization problem used in training a logistic regression classifier by a quadratic (on the number of features) dependency on both training and test times."

But when I experiment it, I found that the predict results seems off, I implemented it with these codes:

```
library(gmodels)
library(AnDE)
AODE_Model = aode(iris)
predict_aode = predict(AODE_Model, iris)
CrossTable(as.numeric(iris$Species), predict_aode)
```

[image: Matrix Table]

Can anyone explain to me about this? or are there any good practical solutions to implement AODE? thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the vignette for the function:

> train: data.frame : training data. It should be a data frame. AODE
>             works only discretized data. It would be better to
>             discreetize the data frame before passing it to this
>             function.However, aode discretizes the data if not done
>             before hand. It uses an R package called discretization for
>             the purpose. It uses the well known MDL discretization
>             technique.(It might fail sometimes)

By default, the discretization function from arules cuts it into 3, which may not be enough for iris. So I first reproduce the result you have with the discretization by arules:

```
library(arules)
library(gmodels)
library(AnDE)
set.seed(111)
trn = sample(1:nrow(indata),100)
test = setdiff(1:nrow(indata),trn)

indata <- data.frame(lapply(iris[,1:4],discretize,breaks=3),Species=iris$Species)
AODE_Model = aode(indata[trn,])
predict_aode = predict(AODE_Model, indata[test,])
CrossTable(as.numeric(indata$Species)[test], predict_aode)

                                 | predict_aode 
as.numeric(indata$Species)[test] |         1 |         3 | Row Total | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                               1 |        15 |         5 |        20 | 
                                 |     0.500 |     4.500 |           | 
                                 |     0.750 |     0.250 |     0.400 | 
                                 |     0.333 |     1.000 |           | 
                                 |     0.300 |     0.100 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                               2 |        11 |         0 |        11 | 
                                 |     0.122 |     1.100 |           | 
                                 |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.220 | 
                                 |     0.244 |     0.000 |           | 
                                 |     0.220 |     0.000 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                               3 |        19 |         0 |        19 | 
                                 |     0.211 |     1.900 |           | 
                                 |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.380 | 
                                 |     0.422 |     0.000 |           | 
                                 |     0.380 |     0.000 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                    Column Total |        45 |         5 |        50 | 
                                 |     0.900 |     0.100 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

You can see one of the classes is missing in prediction. Let's increase it to 4:

```
indata <- data.frame(lapply(iris[,1:4],discretize,breaks=4),Species=iris$Species)
AODE_Model = aode(indata[trn,])
predict_aode = predict(AODE_Model, indata[test,])
CrossTable(as.numeric(indata$Species)[test], predict_aode)

                                 | predict_aode 
as.numeric(indata$Species)[test] |         1 |         2 |         3 | Row Total | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                               1 |        20 |         0 |         0 |        20 | 
                                 |    18.000 |     4.800 |     7.200 |           | 
                                 |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.400 | 
                                 |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
                                 |     0.400 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                               2 |         0 |        10 |         1 |        11 | 
                                 |     4.400 |    20.519 |     2.213 |           | 
                                 |     0.000 |     0.909 |     0.091 |     0.220 | 
                                 |     0.000 |     0.833 |     0.056 |           | 
                                 |     0.000 |     0.200 |     0.020 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                               3 |         0 |         2 |        17 |        19 | 
                                 |     7.600 |     1.437 |    15.091 |           | 
                                 |     0.000 |     0.105 |     0.895 |     0.380 | 
                                 |     0.000 |     0.167 |     0.944 |           | 
                                 |     0.000 |     0.040 |     0.340 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                    Column Total |        20 |        12 |        18 |        50 | 
                                 |     0.400 |     0.240 |     0.360 |           | 
---------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

It gets only 3 wrong. To me, it's a matter of playing with discretization without overfitting, which can be tricky..

Comment: Brilliant explanation! so actually first thing first is to discretize the dataset with a correct break, thankyou :)